# Null distribution of the maximum and FDR control

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

Suppose we have a series of test statistics $T_{1},...,T_{m}$ each
corresponding to a null hypothesis $H_{0}^{j}: \theta_{j} = 0$.
Let $H_{0}: \theta_{1} = \ldots = \theta_{m} = 0$ denote the situation
where every case is null. Also, assume that the distribution of each 
$T_{i}$ is continuous and increasing values of $T_{i}$ indicate greater
evidence against the null hypothesis.

Let $F_{0}$ denote the distribution function of $T_{max} = \max\{T_{1},\ldots,T_{m}\}$ under $H_{0}$,
and let $q_{\alpha}$ denote the upper $\alpha$-tail of $F_{0}$.
Let $V_{m}$ be the number of rejected null hypotheses.

Suppose that we implement the following multiple comparisons
procedure: reject all $H_{0}^{j}$ such that $T_{j} \geq q_{\alpha}$.

I believe this multiple comparisons procedure controls the
family wise error rate in the weak (see [FWER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate)). This is
because under $H_{0}$, $V_{m} \geq 1$ if and only if 
$T_{max} \geq q_{\alpha}$. Hence,
\begin{equation}
P_{H_{0}}( V_{m} \geq 1) = P_{H_{0}}(T_{max} \geq q_{\alpha}) = 
1 - F_{0}(q_{\alpha}) = \alpha.
\end{equation}

My question is the following: does this procedure also control
the FDR at level $\alpha$? Would this FDR control require independence, or
would it hold for any dependence structure among $T_{1},\ldots,T_{m}$?